# Easy Excel 2010 issue with two lists of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two lists of text codes

- text1
- text2
- text3
- text4
- text5
- etc.

and another list with:

- text3
- text2
- etc.

how do I select only those items from the longest/first list which are **not** in the second list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, found this

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/excel-2010-duplicate-unique-values/